# django form post object like php

Tags: python, django

can i post a object to views like php?
If not, how can i do the same result?
thank you so much.

Like the below form

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div>
        <input name="category[0]['name']" type="text" required />
    <input name="category[0]['desc']" type="text" required />
    </div>
    <div>
        <input name="category[1]['name']" type="text" required />
    <input name="category[1]['desc']" type="text" required />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

> If not, how can i do the same result?

You'd need to use formset, refer
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/formsets/